# How to use the date range in PostgreSQL stored function?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, stored-functions

I am new to SQL. I am using PostgreSQL. I have created the stored function called `report`:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report(sensors VARCHAR,fromdate DATE,todate DATE) 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        sensor VARCHAR,
        id INT,
        value INT,
        created_date DATE
) 
AS $$
DECLARE 
    var_r record;
BEGIN
    FOR var_r IN(SELECT 
                        *
                FROM probe_data 
                WHERE probe_data.sensor =sensors AND probe_data.created_date >= fromdate AND  probe_data.created_date <=  todate )  
    LOOP
        sensor := var_r.sensor ; 
        id := var_r.id;
        created_date := var_r.created_date;
        value:= var_r.value;
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to get the data's between two date ranges.When I execute in SQL tool, it returns my desired output. But when I call the function

```
 let sql=  `select * from public.report($1,$2,$3);`
 let values=[req.body.sensors,req.body.fromdates,req.body.todates];
```

from my nodejs program, I am getting the data's out of range.

Here is my screen shot:

[image: scrreen shot from my postgresql query tool]

[image: and this screen shot from my postman.]
[This is the structure of my return table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ESGx.png)

As you can see,In my second screen shot, I'm getting the data out of range. I don't where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why the inefficient cursor loop? And what are the parameters to the function? How exactly is the return type defined? Please **[edit]** your question and show us the **complete** code of the function.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier,I am new to the SQL,so I used https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/
as my source.

Comment: You still haven't shown us the **complete** `create function` statement.

Comment: I have edited the question as you asked @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Looks to me like timezone issues. You seem to be 6 hours off. I would investigate what your Postgres server thinks the timezone is versus what your nodejs program thinks it is. Probably take a look at the Postgres logs to see what is actually being run in the query when it gets to server. You will probably need to at least temporarily bump .```log_statement='all' ``` in postgresql.conf to see the ```SELECT``` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter is declared as `DATE` but you are trying to pass a `timestamp`. So Postgres will cast the passed value to a date and you lose the time information. You need to define the parameter as `timestamp` if you want it to be treated as one. The return type of `created_at` should probably be a `timestamp` as well.

You can also get rid of the CURSOR loop and PL/pgSQL as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report(sensors VARCHAR, fromdate timestamp, todate timestamp) 
    RETURNS TABLE (sensor VARCHAR, id INT, value INT, created_date timestamp) 
AS $$
  select pb.sensor, pb.id, pb.value, pg.created_date
  FROM probe_data 
  WHERE pb.sensor = sensors 
    AND pb.created_date >= fromdate 
    AND pb.created_date <= todate;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: hi sir, thank you for your answer. But I  have to pass the input as JSON and receive the output table as JSON. It would be very kind if you give me some examples.here is my question at stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767987/how-to-extract-the-values-from-json-input-in-postgresql