# How to extract the values from json input in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-functions

I am working with the PostgreSQL stored function, I need to extract the values from the JSON input and match with the column in the table and return the table in JSON format.
My JSON input,

```
{
"sensor":"sensor1",
"fromdate":date,
"todate":"date
}
```

[my sensortable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufiOT.png)
here is the function I worked so far

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
      from (
        select sensor,id,value,created_date
        from probe_data
        where  probe_data.sensor =sensors
         AND probe_data.created_date >=fromdate AND  probe_data.created_date <= todate
      ) d
select x.sensores,x.fromdate,x.todate from json_to_recordset($1) x
(
sensors text,
fromdate timestamp,
todate timestamp)
```

As you can see, I can able to get the data from JSON input but I don't know how to access it inside the WHERE condition. I need some help to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can use `JSONB` operators to achieve this like below:

Try this:

```
create or replace function example (param1 jsonb) 
returns table (sensor_ varchar, id_ int, value_ numeric, created_date_ TIMESTAMP) 
as 
$body$
    begin
    RETURN query
    select sensor, id, value, created_date from probe_data 
    where 
    created_date >=(param1->>'fromdate')::TIMESTAMP 
    and 
    created_date <= (param1->>'todate')::TIMESTAMP;

    end;

$body$ 

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

if you want the above output in `JSON ARRAY` format then

Try This:

```
create or replace function example1 (param1 jsonb) 
returns jsonb 
as 
$body$
declare 
    jsondata jsonb;

begin
    
    jsondata = (select 
            array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d))) from (
            select sensor, id, value, created_date from probe_data 
            where 
            created_date >=(param1->>'fromdate')::TIMESTAMP 
            and 
            created_date <= (param1->>'todate')::TIMESTAMP ) d);
RETURN jsondata;
end;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f490d34e3ffc74dc1ad96406016f198a)

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, but I am getting null as result

Comment: are you putting same `fromdate` and `todate`

Comment: create or replace function reportsss (param1 jsonb) 
returns jsonb 
as 
$body$
declare 
jsondata jsonb;
begin
jsondata = (select 
            array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d))) from (
            select sensor, id, value, created_date 
            from probe_data 
            where 
    sensor =(param1->>'sensor')::varchar
    and
            created_date >=(param1->>'fromdate')::TIMESTAMP 
            and 
            created_date <= (param1->>'todate')::TIMESTAMP ) d);
RETURN jsondata;
end;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: i mean value of `fromdate` and `todate` in input json

Comment: I am passing values like this,
SELECT * from public.reportsss('[{
  "fromdate": "2020-02-03T12:02",
"sensor": "System1.orp.orp",
"todate": "2020-07-04T12:02"
}]')

Comment: I have added the example. you check whether any data exist in this date range. one more thing in question you have mentioned JSON Object but above you are passing JSON ARRAY. in above value remove [ ]. it will work.

Comment: sir, thank you so much.I really mean that thanks a lot.it worked